# 'angular-ui-grid' Expanded row issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

After the update, google chrome (ver:77) from (ver:76) expanded row not working as expected.
Before update google chrome expanded row of 'angular-UI-grid' was working properly, However, It's working fine in other browsers like Mozilla Firefox and Microsoft Edge and also working in older Version(76.0.3809.132) of chrome.

Before the update, google chrome expanded row open with proper space and expand, other row showing after expanded area.
[image]

After the update, google chrome expanded row open to overlay other rows.
[image]

Comment: Please make a code snippet that reproduces your problem. Or at least share the `css` styles applied to the element that is causing the problem. Otherwise, how could we help you ?

Comment: I assume it's a css bug, not js. Maybe a missing clear-tag inside the row or wrong display/position-attribute. Can you share the css and html?

Comment: I am only using 'angular UI grid' library CSS and nothing change in CSS recently. Because of my deployed code is not changed. and if I check my deployed code in my laptop with newly updated chrome (V-77) it's showing a distorted view of grid and if I am using the same machine with other versions of google chrome (v-76) it works.

Comment: with adding some css it's get fixed for me                                                        
 .ui-grid-row {
   clear: both;
   }

Answer (score 2):

Updating the css for class .ui-grid-row {clear : both} worked up for me